# Laptop key sticking down from lots of use

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My Acer Aspire 7741 keyboard's <kbd>W</kbd> key has been used a lot due to gaming, and now it sticks down a little bit when I play and hold it for an extended time. The keyboard isn't sticky from a spilled drink or anything. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely debris stuck in your key spring mechanism.

I had a similar problem but with the N key. After a year I decided to pop up the key even if I permanently broke it. I found a finger nail clipping was lodged in the plastic spring.

Comment: I just checked ad there isn't anything under it.

Comment: If the mechanism separates from the spring mechanism I would then replace the mechanism from another key in that row you don't use. I say that row because sometime each row has a different height spring. If they are all the same then switch it with an unused key if you can...  OR you can by a [keyboard replacement](http://www.amazon.com/Keyboard-Aspire-Replacement-AS5810T-8952-NSK-AL01D/dp/B004Z4UAIE) for about $15 and keep the old pad for spare keys...

Comment: Wow I never knew that. Buying a new keyboard is not an option for the next month because I will be traveling, so thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I reseated the key and it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

New keyboards are pretty cheap and can be found on Amazon. $10-$40 and fairly easy to install. In the mean time, try side stepping or retreating. ;)